# ether_addr_octet in host order byte

Tags: c, ethernet

I would like convert struct ether_addr (ether_addr_octet) to integer host byte order representation. Any ideas?

```
ntohl(eth->ether_addr_octet)
```

not working, because `ether_addr_octet` is a char array.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the semantics of this are going to be.
The ether is 48bit, and the largest ntoh* is for 32bit values.
I suppose you can create a 64bit value parsing the char array, and calling ntohl() twice...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to char and then you can do something else you want...

```
char *ether_ntoa_my(const struct ether_addr *addr){
    static char buf[18];
    sprintf(buf, "%02x%02x:%02x%02x:%02x%02x",
            addr->ether_addr_octet[0], addr->ether_addr_octet[1],
            addr->ether_addr_octet[2], addr->ether_addr_octet[3],
            addr->ether_addr_octet[4], addr->ether_addr_octet[5]);
    return buf;
}
```

I hope it helps